# Fillna on slice which is in other dataframe

Tags: pandas, slice, fillna

I would like to change a function that takes a **single value** in the Indicator column to fillna(0) the Values column of a stacked dataframe to work with a **list of indicators** for which Nan values should be set to zero.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ISO3': ['Australia', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Canada', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Canada'], 
                   'Year': [1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991],
                   'Indicator' : ['Disaster Fatalities', 'Disaster Fatalities', 'Disaster Fatalities', 'Disaster Fatalities', 'Oil Reserves', 'Oil Reserves', 'Oil Reserves', 'Oil Reserves' ],
                   'Value' : [np.nan, 5, np.nan, 18, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
                  })
df.head(8)
```

Gives:

```
ISO3    Year    Indicator   Value
0   Australia   1991    Disaster Fatalities NaN
1   Austria 1991    Disaster Fatalities 5.0
2   Belgium 1991    Disaster Fatalities NaN
3   Canada  1991    Disaster Fatalities 18.0
4   Australia   1991    Oil Reserves    NaN
5   Austria 1991    Oil Reserves    NaN
6   Belgium 1991    Oil Reserves    NaN
7   Canada  1991    Oil Reserves    NaN
```

Function for setting Nan values to zero for single indicator:

```
def zerofillnaindicator (df, Indicators):
    mask = (df['Indicator'] == Indicators)
    df.loc[mask, 'Value'] = df.loc[mask, 'Value'].fillna(0)
    return df
```

Called with

```
df2 = zerofillnaindicator (df = df, Indicators = 'Disaster Fatalities')
df2.head(8)
```

Gives as desired:

```
ISO3    Year    Indicator   Value
0   Australia   1991    Disaster Fatalities 0.0
1   Austria 1991    Disaster Fatalities 5.0
2   Belgium 1991    Disaster Fatalities 0.0
3   Canada  1991    Disaster Fatalities 18.0
4   Australia   1991    Oil Reserves    NaN
5   Austria 1991    Oil Reserves    NaN
6   Belgium 1991    Oil Reserves    NaN
7   Canada  1991    Oil Reserves    NaN
```

But how do I change this to take a list of Indicators like this:

```
df2 = zerofillnaindicator (df = df, Indicators = ['Disaster Fatalities', 'Oil Reserves'])
df2.head(8)
```

I tried replacing the condition for the mask with **df.isin(Indicators)** but this resulted in a 'Cannot index with multidimensional key' error on the .isin function

```
def zerofillnaindicator (df, Indicators):
    mask = df.isin(Indicators)
    df.loc[mask, 'Value'] = df.loc[mask, 'Value'].fillna(0)
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

If need working with scalar or with list in same function use `isinstance` for convert scalar to one element list:

```
def zerofillnaindicator (df, Indicators):
    vals = [Indicators] if isinstance(Indicators, str) else Indicators

    mask = df['Indicator'].isin(vals)
    df.loc[mask, 'Value'] = df.loc[mask, 'Value'].fillna(0)
    return df

df2 = zerofillnaindicator (df = df, Indicators = 'Disaster Fatalities')
print (df2)
        ISO3  Year            Indicator  Value
0  Australia  1991  Disaster Fatalities    0.0
1    Austria  1991  Disaster Fatalities    5.0
2    Belgium  1991  Disaster Fatalities    0.0
3     Canada  1991  Disaster Fatalities   18.0
4  Australia  1991         Oil Reserves    NaN
5    Austria  1991         Oil Reserves    NaN
6    Belgium  1991         Oil Reserves    NaN
7     Canada  1991         Oil Reserves    NaN

df3 = zerofillnaindicator (df = df, Indicators = ['Disaster Fatalities', 'Oil Reserves'])
print (df3)
        ISO3  Year            Indicator  Value
0  Australia  1991  Disaster Fatalities    0.0
1    Austria  1991  Disaster Fatalities    5.0
2    Belgium  1991  Disaster Fatalities    0.0
3     Canada  1991  Disaster Fatalities   18.0
4  Australia  1991         Oil Reserves    0.0
5    Austria  1991         Oil Reserves    0.0
6    Belgium  1991         Oil Reserves    0.0
7     Canada  1991         Oil Reserves    0.0
```

Comment: Do you mean like this: 'mask = np.array(df.isin(Indicators).values)'? I still get ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)

Comment: Wonderful! Now I just have to study the code to understand it:-)

Comment: @Laurens - There is used [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)